# How to include html in a WinJS converter

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I am trying to create a converter to concatenate 2 properties. I would like to style one of them to be italic.

```
fooConverter: WinJS.Binding.converter(function (model) {
     return model.foo + ' ' + '<i>' + model.foo2 + '</i>';
}
```

and my markup is

```
<h2 data-win-bind="innerText: model.name"></h2>
```

However, the output of this is

```
Foo <i>Foo2</i>
```

instead of making Foo2 italic.  Is it possible to do this with converters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<h2 data-win-bind="innerHTML: model.name"></h2>` instead.